# Is it formally correct to say that a vector is equal to the subtraction of two points?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I am in the first period of Physics, and the Analytical Geometry teacher said that it is wrong to say that $\overrightarrow{AB} = B - A$,
considering A and B any two points in a vector space, because the subtraction of points is not defined. But if this is true, then it would be incorrect to even say that $\overrightarrow{v} = (x_2 - x_1)/ Δt$. So, in fact, is it formally wrong to subtract two points from a vector space?

Comment: It is often commented that physicists bend the rules of mathematics to achieve goals, and some of these rule-bending events have resulted in new approaches and understanding in mathematics.

Comment: But this is an straightforward (almost not worth mentioning) abuse of notation where you represent the point $B$ and the (position) vector for $B$ by the same letter, and once you pass to vectors the subtraction is easily defined